# What can I do about my matted hair?

Tags: hair

I have a mat in my hair. It is kind of impossible to pierce the mat I have. It’s not even that big but I can’t put my comb through it... What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple options for you.

1. Speak with a hairdresser. They may be able to do something with your hair, or they could recommend a product used for serious untangling.
2. You could just cut it off (even if you need to shave your head).

Answer (score 1):

- Ensure you hair is damp.
- Get coconut oil, or olive oil.
- Apply the oil oil to your hair from roots to ends.
- Let it set for about 30 minutes.
- Get a wide teeth comb.
- Comb from ends to roots to avoid loosing a whole lot of hair.
- Rinse hair out with warm water.
- Shampoo with sulfate free shampoo.
- Apply a hair mask to hair and sit under a steamer for 20 minutes.
- Rinse with warm water.
- Apply moisturizer to hair and style as desired